# How Can I Detect A Data Type in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, types

I'd like to make a call to a function and send either a string or an integer...

```
function getImage(val:*):void{
    if(val == String){
        switch(val){

            case'next':
            loadNext();
            break;

            case'prev':
            loadPrev();
            break
        }
    }else{
        loadImg(val);
    }
}
```

and vary my function accordingly... anyone know how to detect the parameter type?

Thanks
-J

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `is` keyword:

```
if(val is String) {
  //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the method typeof()

for example:

```
var myTest:String = 'This is a string';
trace(typeof(myTest));
```

This will trace out string